MongoDB - Remove object element in array inside another object
Keep it short.
I have:
{
  _id: "694201337",             //_id => user id
  skills: [
    {
      sId: "420",       //sId => Skill id
      title: "Coding",
      level: 69,
      goals: [
        {
          gId: "1337",   //gId => Goal id
          title: "3hr/week",
          text: "Code atleast 3 hours every week"
        },
        {
          gId: "12345",   //gId => Goal id
          title: "Simulation",
          text: "Create a python simulation game"
        } 
      ]
    }
  ]
}
        

I want to remove a goal object from the goals array, from a specific skill object from the skills array, from the user.
So if I want to remove the goal with the id (gId) of "1337", it should look like this after:
{
  _id: "694201337",             //_id => user id
  skills: [
    {
      sId: "420",       //sId => Skill id
      title: "Coding",
      level: "69",
      goals: [
        {
          gId: "12345",   //gId => Goal id
          title: "Simulation",
          text: "Create a python simulation game"
        } 
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I have my collection as:
const Collection

What is the correct command to get the result I want?
I should point out that all IDs are known.
Something like:
Collection.update({_id: "694201337"}, {$pull: { skills : {skill : {goal.gId: "1337"}}}


You can work with dot notation and all positional operator ($[]) to remove all the "goal" elements with gId: "1337.
db.collection.update({
  _id: "694201337",
  "skills.goals.gId": "1337"
},
{
  $pull: {
    "skills.$[].goals": {
      gId: "1337"
    }
  }
})

Demo @ Mongo Playground

This looks promising :). Does it work if there's multiple skills? I can update my post to make it more clear if you want

Yes, the $[] operator will remove the matched goal elements no matter it is located in which skill element. You can try to play with the Mongo Playgrouond link I shared by adding more skill elements with/without matching goal element.

Tried it out with the playground and it worked out as intended as long as the goals id are not the same (which they never should be). Thank you very much! :)
